# What are some examples of modern economic research that integrate economics and computer science?

Tags: computation

I am entering my first year of graduate studies in Economics this fall and I'm curious about which areas of economic research utilize various fields of computer science (e.g. Machine Learning, Graph Theory, etc.) to study economics. More specifically, how are recent advancements in the field of computer science being used to answer economic questions that were previously difficult or impossible to answer?
Thank you in advance for any responses.

Answer (score 1):

I can try to give a bunch of examples about specific branches in economics that have been reshaped by computer science over the last decade, but I will leave this to the ones that are more knowledgeable, and far better writers.

That being said, I really enjoyed Hal Varian's take away of it:

https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/jep.28.2.3

And this video where Susan Athey elaborates upon the role of machine learning in the study of causal effects and their connection with impact evaluation literature:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VeTl4mIdqWA

Good luck in your studies!